# Sum donations (variables) for several accounts

Tags: php, mysql

```sql
-- Table structure for table 'members'
CREATE TABLE `members` (
`mID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`fname` VARCHAR(50), 
`lname` VARCHAR(50), 
`status` VARCHAR(20), 
`dateregistered` VARCHAR(255), 
INDEX (`lname`), 
PRIMARY KEY (`mID`)
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Table structure for table 'payments'
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
`paymentsID` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`amount` INTEGER, 
`type` VARCHAR(255), 
`officer` VARCHAR(255), 
`dayentered` DATETIME, 
`mID` INTEGER, 
INDEX (`mID`), 
PRIMARY KEY (`paymentsID`)
) ENGINE=myisam DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have the above two tables in my database. The database keeps information on donations that are categorised according to their account type (for utility bills, building projects etc) and members donate directly to a particular account of their choice (they can donate to one account or to all account or any number of accounts).

The database was working fine in MS Access but now I have to migrate it to MySQL and PHP and that's where my problem lies. I can not manage to come up with the code to list the names of the members and for each member show the total amount donated for each account per month as well as a running total for the year.

Please help with the code. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can start by modifying your question to include the query in Access.

Answer (score 0):

Not as fast/efficient as a pure SQL solution, but this would do the job.

```
$query = "
SELECT 
  `members`.`mID`,
  `members`.`fname`, 
  `members`.`lname`, 
  `payments`.`amount`, 
  `payments`.`type`, 
  `payments`.`dayentered`
FROM `members` JOIN `payments` 
ON `members`.`mID` = `payments`.`mID`";
$result = mysqli($link, $query);
$results = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $mID    = $row['mID'];
  $type   = $row['type'];
  $amount = (int) $row['amount'];
  $date   = $row['dayentered'];
  $year   = date('Y', strtotime($date));

  if(!array_key_exists($mid, $results)) 
    $results[$mid] = array($row['fname'], $row['lname']);

  if(!array_key_exists($date, $results[$mid])) 
    $results[$mid][$date] = array();

  if(!array_key_exists($type, $results[$mid][$date])) 
    $results[$mid][$date][$type] = $amount;
  else
    $results[$mid][$date][$type] += $amount;

  if(!array_key_exists($year, $results[$mid]))
    $results[$mid][$year] = $amount;
  else
    $results[$mid][$year] += $amount;

}
```

Comment: Tried this in a php page but got an error. Inserted my php code to your code as follows

Comment: Tried this in a php page but got an error. Inserted my php code to the code but it returns this error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli() in C:\Program Files\VertrigoServ\www\church\details.php on line 12.  Line 12 has the following $result = mysqli($link, $query);
Please help

Comment: So you don't have `mysqli` support and need to use `mysql` functions instead. Use `$result = mysql($query);` instead of `$result = mysqli($link, $query);` and `while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {` instead of `while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {`. Remember that you need a working mysql connection before you execute this code which is not covered here.

Comment: I have a php connection file that works fine with the other php file which simply list the members. It is from this list that i have a Details link on which if one clicks on it he is supposed to be led to the Deatails page that will have the details of the payment. Its this page that is not working even after using your code. The problems that i am failing to properly build the php page with your code. The page is supposed to list payments details with this link echo '<td><a href="details.php?mID=' . $row['mID'] . '">Click here for Details</a></td>';. Thanks for your usual quick help.

Comment: By the way i am using VERTRIGO as my testing server (it supports mysqli and php 5 only that i am a true self taught newbie to sql and php)

Comment: i have reviewed my question to add the code for the dxetails.php where i want to insert the code

Comment: @user2159175 please ask specific questions if you need help. What error do you get with the updated code? You say you have mysqli, whereas error *Call to undefined function mysqli()* which you previously reported proves the opposite.

Comment: My specific problem is that the code you have given me is supposed to be part of a php file that displays the account details. Now I can not properly incorporate your code into the php file. Hope this clears things abit.